# Apache Flink SQL - Slow Results When Using LAG Function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a very simple SQL query, running in AWS Kinesis Data Analytics, reading from a Kinesis Stream. When I use the LAG Function, the performance is really slow, when returning the results. In some cases minutes, compared to ms without the `lag` function.

```
SUDO CODE
SELECT 'COLUMN1', lag(COLUMN1) over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY event_time ASC) as previous_value
FROM TABLE
```

Any suggestions of why this is happening would be much appreciated.

*UPDATE*

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    `specversion` STRING,
    `type` STRING,
    `id` STRING ,
    event_sid as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.sid'),
    task_sid as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_sid'),
    reservation_sid as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.reservation_sid'),
    event_type as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.eventtype'),
    agent_name as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.worker_attributes'), '$.full_name'),
    queue as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_queue_name'),
    direction as CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.direction') is null THEN 'Inbound' else JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.direction')  end,
    reservation_version as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.reservation_version'),
    -- Business Attributes
    brand as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.conversations.case'),
    country as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.conversations.campaign'),
    product as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.conversations.content'),
    business_channel as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.conversations.initiative'),
    `language` as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.conversations.language'),
    handling_department_name as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.conversations.handling_department_name'),
    handling_team_name as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.conversations.handling_team_name'),
    conversation_id as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.conversations.conversation_id'),
    communication_channel as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_channel_unique_name'),
    task_age_in_queue AS JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_age_in_queue' RETURNING integer),
    task_age AS JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_age'  RETURNING integer),
    task_age_in_queue2 AS JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes.callStartDateTime'),
    `time` string,
    `data` STRING,
    task_attributes as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'),
    callStartDateTime as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.callStartDateTime'),
    call_start_date_time as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes.callStartDateTime'),
    conference as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes.conference'),
    segments  as JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_attributes'), '$.task_attributes.segments'),
    record_time AS TO_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(left(`time`, CHAR_LENGTH(`time`) - 1), 'T', ' ')),
    task_assignment_status as JSON_VALUE(data, '$.payload.task_assignment_status'),
    proc_time AS PROCTIME(),
    WATERMARK FOR record_time AS record_time - INTERVAL '1' second,
    PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
    
 )
 WITH (
   'connector' = 'kinesis',
   'stream' = '',
   'aws.region' = '',
  
   'scan.stream.initpos' = 'AT_TIMESTAMP',
   'scan.stream.initpos-timestamp' = '2023-07-29T18:18:00.000-00:00',
   'format' = 'json',
   'scan.stream.recordpublisher' = 'EFO',
   'scan.stream.efo.consumername' = 'App',
   'scan.stream.efo.registration' = 'LAZY'
 );
```

Comment: In the case you are comparing to, without the lag function, did you still have the over window? I can see how the ORDER BY could incur a significant cost in terms of latency, but if that's not the explanation, I'm not sure. How is your watermarking configured? How frequently are new events arriving?

Comment: Hi David, without the lag function, i have no over window.

Comment: I have added source table to post, with the watermarking.

Comment: The events are arriving at several hundred a second.

Comment: Update: @DavidAnderson I have observed today in production, that the latency has vastly reduced, when the volumes increase.Is there perhaps a setting related to buffer, that i can reduce so during slower periods, i still get the same low latency?

Answer (score 0):

The over window has to buffer enough of the table to handle the one second of out-of-orderness you've built into the watermarking. That's putting some load on the state backend that otherwise wasn't happening without the lag and over window.

If you have access to the Flink dashboard (or metrics) you could check to see if the job is backpressured when it's slow, and where the bottleneck is. Perhaps when the load is higher, you need to scale up in order to be able to keep up.

This query could be rewritten as a MATCH_RECOGNIZE pattern matching query. That would also have to do the same buffered sort that the over window is doing, so I wouldn't expect the performance to be any different, but without trying it, I can't be sure.